# ReferenceError: wp is not defined

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have added simple field plugin in my wordpress site

In "scripts.js" file it gives me error ReferenceError: wp is not defined.

Below is the line of code where wp is used in my file.

```
my.media_frame = wp.media({
        state: 'mystate',
        className: 'media-frame simple-fields-media-frame',
        frame: 'select', // select | post. select removed left nav (insert media, create gallery, set featured image)
        multiple: false,
        title: _wpMediaViewsL10n.mediaLibraryTitle,
        button: {
            text: _wpMediaViewsL10n.insertIntoPost
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Howlin.

Can you please reply to my question.